# In a GLM fit, is the intercept equal to the mean of the data?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, glmnet

If a GLM fit is applied to the dataset it was fit to, should the means of the predictions and the data be the same? I assume in a penalised GLM (e.g. using glmnet in R) this is't the case, but is it true for the general case? What problems would I cause if I scaled the factors (or just the intercept if I'm fitting to the logs) so that this was true?

Comment: I am puzzled as to why you would think that.

Comment: @Michael Because it is true of some GLMs (provided there is an intercept term).

Comment: Regarding the question in the title (which does not match the body of the question): yes, if it's a linear model and the predictors are centered. In a GLM that uses a link function, the intercept is on a different scale from the outcome variable.